# How to print out the individual price of an item in a shopping list

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this code:

```
 stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:
        item = shopping_list(prices[key])
        total += item
    return total
shopping_list = ["pear", "orange", "apple"] 
total = sum([ prices[s] for s in shopping_list ])

print("Items Purchased")
print("---------------")
for items in shopping_list:
    print(items.title() + " @" + )
print("---------------")
print("Total: £{:.2f}".format(total))
```

I am wondering if I am able to print out the prices of each item as you can see I've tried to no avail.

Comment: Why is `compute_bill` there? what is `key`? Please keep your example minimal and your question concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a function here this can easily be done without it.

```
stock ={
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

shopping_cart = ["pear", "orange", "apple"]

shopping_cart = [("pear",1), ("orange", 3), ("apple",10)]

for i in shopping_cart:
    if stock[i[0]] - i[1] < 0:
        shopping_cart.pop(shopping_cart.index(i))
    else:
        stock[i[0]] -= i[1]

print("----------------")
print("     Bill")
print("----------------")
for i in shopping_cart:
    print(f"{i[0]} x{i[1]} @  £{prices[i[0]]}")
print("----------------")
print(sum([prices[i[0]] * i[1]  for i in shopping_cart]))
print("----------------")
```

explanation:

the shopping cart

- made up of tuples
- first element it item
- second is the amount

first for loop

- checks if there is sufficient stock to purchase that item, if there is then it removes that amount from the stock and proceeds
- if not it removes that item from the shopping cart (yes you could modify it that when there is not sufficient stock but stock is > 0 you sell the user the remaining stock.)

second for loop

- uses an f string to format the output

sum (list comprehension)

- easily gets the sum of the price of the item * the amount being purchased!

Comment: yes, but if you see near the bottom i want to be able to tell the user what item they7 bought and how much it was from the list, would that be at all possible?

```print("Items Purchased")
print("---------------")
for items in shopping_list:
    print(items.title() + " @" + )
print("---------------")
print("Total: £{:.2f}".format(total))```

Comment: Oh ok thats easy enough, do you want me to add support for multiples of one item?

Comment: Thank you! Would it be possible for me to add the format function to get ```Pear @ £1.5``` to display as ```Pear @ £1.50```

Comment: yes, also i forgot about removing from stock that has been added as well :)

Comment: thanks for asking, i hope the explanation helps you understand what i did there, happy coding!

Comment: I also add this bit just for fun as I realised that most places probably charge tax on food items.
```total = (sum([prices[i[0]] * i[1]  for i in shopping_cart]))
total_after_tax = total + (total*0.2)
tax_total = total_after_tax - total
print("Tax @ 20%")
print("Subtotal before tax: £{:.2f}".format(total))
print("Total after tax: £{:.2f}".format(total_after_tax))
print("Tax is: £{:.2f}".format(tax_total))
print("----------------")```

Comment: Okay so, I am trying to get the total of the items bought by the customer. i have tried ```for i in shopping_cart:
    print(f"{i[0]} x{i[1]} @  £{prices[i[0]]}")
    total_items = sum({i[1]})``` and then done ```print(f"{total_items} items bought!")``` but it returns 0. How would I go about getting the right answer?

Comment: the total items? So like a number would be `sum([i[1] for i in shopping_cart]`)

Comment: thank you so much. sorry about all the hassle, I'm just trying to learn this for the future. Seriously thank you!

Comment: Im glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the function `compute_bill` return current item, price and also check if the item is in stock. If it's available, decrease the amount.

```
stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}


def compute_bill(shopping_list):
    for item in shopping_list:
        if stock.get(item, 0) > 0:
            yield item, prices.get(item, 0), 
            stock[item] -= 1


shopping_list = ["pear", "orange", "apple"] 

print("Items Purchased")
print("---------------")

total = 0
for item, value in compute_bill(shopping_list):
    print('{:<10} @{}'.format(item.title(), value))
    total += value

print("---------------")
print("Total: £{:.2f}".format(total))
```

Prints:

```
Items Purchased
---------------
Pear       @3
Orange     @1.5
---------------
Total: £4.50
```

Comment: would it be possible to fortmat the pear @3 to show as Pear @ £3?